# How to merge all columns into one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've merged a three tables into one table and I've noticed that each merged table has similar data columns producing redundancy.

What is the best way to update all of these columns into one column?

Right now the data will read

```
WallJambHeadCut | WallJambSillCut | DoorJambSillCut | DoorJambHeadCut | ect ....
       1               0                0                   0 
       0               0                1                   0
```

The above needs to be condensed down too two columns:

```
  Headcut | SillCut
```

In other words each one of these columns can be condensed into one. I just want to make sure that I write the correct update statement because I would hate the jack my data up.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WallJambHeadCut] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [WallJambSillCut] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DoorJambSillCut] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DoorJambHeadCut] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [VerticalHeadCut] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [VerticalSillCut] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the complexity you want to do, you can replace all the columns with a column of type tinyint and do bitwise operations to handle the data. We actually do that in the project I'm working on.

For the example you gave, you will have

```
0000 1000  --Which is 8
0000 0010  --Which is 2
```

Whenever you need to update these values you just use the operators.

You can check more information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx

The tinyint is better because it only occupies 8 bits

1. Add the new column
2. update the table and set newCol = WallJambHeadCut | WallJambSillCut | DoorJambSillCut | DoorJambHeadCut --For each row

Cheers

Comment: I didn't even think about oRing ... Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get what you want from this query?

```
select Headcut,Sillcut from (
select [WallJambHeadCut] as Headcut,[WallJambSillCut] as Sillcut from table_1 
union all
select [DoorJambHeadCut] as Headcut,[DoorJambSillCut] as Sillcut from table_1 
union all
select [VerticalHeadCut] as Headcut),[VerticalSillCut] as Sillcut from table_1 
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Create on column of type int, and store/read/update data using bitwise operations. For example use first bit for col1, second bit for col2 and third bit for col3 etc. (assuming that you have only two possibilities for for each column).